# I want to sum every 24 cells in a worksheet

Tags: excel, function, sum, sumifs

For example I want to sum the values inside the the column K: K3 + K27 + K51 + K75 etc

Thanks

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/sum-every-nth-row.html

Answer (score 2):

Array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(MOD(ROW(K:K)-3,24)=0,K:K,0))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bwyn, worked like a charm for me ;)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Please mark this as the answer.